# simulating a simple linear model

Tags: r, linear-regression, simulation

I'm trying to simulate a simple linear model 100 times and find the LS estimation of B1 from the linear model.

```
set.seed(123498)
x<-rnorm(z, 0, 1)
e<-rnorm(z, 0 ,2)
y<-0.5 + 2*x + e
model<- lm(y~x)
simulaten=100
z=10

for (i in 1:simulaten){
  e<-rnorm(n, 0 ,2)
  x<-rnorm(n, 0, 1)
  y<-0.5 + 2*x + e
  model<- lm(y~x)}
  summary(model)
```

Is that what my for loop is achieving or have i missed the mark?

Comment: You are updating the `model` in each iteration.  So, the `summary(model)` is from the last iteration

Comment: Should I use the replicate function if I want to store it as a vector?

Comment: Yes, `replicate` is also useful.  then you can avoid a `for` loop.  i.e. `replicate(simulaten, yourcode, simplify = FALSE)`

Comment: Thanks for the clarification!

Comment: It would be `replicate(simulaten, ...` instead of `length`.  `replicate` can either return an array (`simplify = TRUE)` or a list.  I would rather get it in a list because you have many options to work with list (e.g. lapply, sapply, vapply, Map, mapply)

Comment: Do I use replicate on each line of code I want to iterate?

Comment: RuiBarradas showed an option with replicate.  You could check that solution. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a `replicate` solution. I have set `n` (forgotten in the question) and `simulaten` to a smaller value.

```
n <- 100
simulaten <- 4

set.seed(123498)

model_list <- replicate(simulaten, {
      e <- rnorm(n, 0, 2)
      x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
      y <- 0.5 + 2*x + e
      lm(y ~ x)
}, simplify = FALSE)

model_list
```

## Edit

Several statistics can be obtained from the models list. The coefficients are extracted with function `coef` applied to each model.
Done with `sapply`, the returned object is a 2 rows matrix.

```
betas <- sapply(model_list, coef)

str(betas)
# num [1:2, 1:1000] 0.671 1.875 0.374 2.019 0.758 ...
# - attr(*, "dimnames")=List of 2
#  ..$ : chr [1:2] "(Intercept)" "x"
#  ..$ : NULL
```

As for the graph, here is an example. Note that in order for the x axis to reach all the x values, in the first call to `hist` argument `xlim` is set to `range(betas)`.

```
lgd <- c(expression(beta[0]), expression(beta[1]))
hist(betas[1, ], freq = FALSE, col = "lightblue", xlim = range(betas), ylim = c(0, 2.5), xlab = "betas", main = "")
hist(betas[2, ], freq = FALSE, col = "blue", add = TRUE)
legend("top", legend = lgd, fill = c("lightblue", "blue"), horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Is there a way of pulling the values of b0_hat and b1_hat from the coefficient summary and putting them into a vector so I can make a histogram? And thank you for the clear and concise answer!

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

The `model` is updated in each of the iteration.  So the `summary` is returning the summary output of the last 'model'.  We could store it in a `list`.

```
# // initialize empty list of length equals length of simulaten
modellst <- vector('list', simulaten)
 for(i in seq_len(simulaten)) {
      e <- rnorm(n, 0 ,2)
      x <- rnorm(n, 0, 1)
      y <- 0.5 + 2*x + e
      # // assign the model output to the corresponding list element
      modellst[[i]] <- lm(y~x)  
 }
```

Comment: Upvote but bug: use `seq_len(simulaten)`, or `seq_along(modellst)`.

Comment: Will the results of the iterations be stored in a vector? Sorry for the basic questions. I'm fairly new to R

Comment: @NeilsonsMilk A model object is a complex object with lots of attributes.  A `list` can containerized it well instead of a vector.  Because `vector` can have only a single type